# How to set all repeated values in a column to blank cells in python or excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel-formula

[image: I have data on quarterly market values for a large cross-section of american firms. Some firms were either delisted or acquired by other companies. Datastream automatically repeats the last available value after this date. I need to change all these repetead values to blank cells. Any clue on how I can achieve that on python?]

I have data on quarterly market values for a large cross-section of american firms. Some firms were either delisted or acquired by other companies. Datastream automatically repeats the last available value after this date. I need to change all these repetead values to blank cells up to the last observation of my dataset. Any clue on how I can achieve that on python?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking and your file is an excel file, something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('path to your excel file')

for col in df.columns:
    df[col][df[col].duplicated()] = np.nan #you could replace this with an empty string or whatever
```

Here is a toy example so you can see what this would do

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"], "B":[0,1,1,1], "C":["A","A","B","A"]})

for col in df.columns:
    df[col][df[col].duplicated()] = np.nan #you could replace this with an empty string or whatever

print(df)
```

Once you are happy with the df, you can also save it as an excel file or csv with pandas to_csv or to_excel.

Comment: Give what I have there a try and let me know if that is what you are looking for. If it is not, it would be better if you could post any errors you are getting or say what you would like to work differently first.

Comment: Yes that is kind of what I am looking for. Ideally, I would like to remove repeated values only when a same value is repeated more than n times in a row. Because I want to remove data after a firm was delisted or acquired but I don't want to lose data in the periods when the firms was still active

Comment: df[col].duplicated().sum() will give you the total number of duplicates in a column. df[col].duplicated().rolling(n).sum() will give you the rolling sum over n entries, so you could see if there is any point in the column where the sum was equal to n and remove from there. You could run into unlucky cases where that would fail, but I would think that would be rare. Not sure if there is a more elegant solution. I will be interested to see if anyone else answers